# Azure Migration Service with Cassandra and Cosmos

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

Does anyone know when Azure's Migration Service is going to be compatible with migrating Cassandra data over to Cosmos DB?  I heard the team might be working on it a while ago and I'm wondering if there have been any updates as to when it will be available/if it's still happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-import-data),you could find two options to copy data from existing Cassandra workloads to Azure Cosmos DB.

[1.Using cqlsh COPY command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-import-data#migrate-data-using-spark)

[2.Using Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-import-data#migrate-data-using-spark)

However,[the data migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) is still not support Cassandra API so far.You could submit [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db?category_id=323344) here to push the progress of whatever you want.

Comment: Question was when cassandra would be supported but thanks anyways